# Create an Observable from event delegate

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I have to map input from device hardware done with a native driver in that way:

```
GIS_LF_API.TSLF_SetReaderMode(handle, 1);
GIS_LF_API.TSLF_StartAutoRead(handle, '\r', AutoReadProc);
```

`AutoReadProc` is invoked when the input come from the hardware and is defined in that way to call my OnCallback method:

```
private GIS_LF_API.AutoReadCallback AutoReadProc = OnCallback;
private static int OnCallback(string Arr, int Len)
{
    //do somethings
    return intValue;
}
```

where `AutoReadCallback` into driver is defined like this:

```
public delegate int AutoReadCallback([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pData, int Len);
```

now i want to map an `Observable<int>` when the event is called. 
How is possible to do? I have tried with `Observable.FromEventPattern` but i have not find a way to map it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either stick an Event around the delegate, then use `Observable.FromEvent` (probably preferred), or stick a `Subject` in your handler, and expose the subject as an observable.

Event solution:

```
public class X
{
    public X()
    {
        AutoReadProc += OnCallback; //If still necessary.
        IntObservable = Observable.FromEvent<GIS_LF_API.AutoReadCallback, int>(h => AutoReadProc += h, h => AutoReadProc -= h);
    }

    public event GIS_LF_API.AutoReadCallback AutoReadProc;
    private int OnCallback(string Arr, int Len)
    {
        //do something, if necessary. Not required for observable.
        var intValue = 0;
        return intValue;
    }
    public IObservable<int> IntObservable { get; }

}
```

Subject solution:

```
public class Y
{
    private readonly Subject<int> _subject = new Subject<int>();
    public Y()
    {
        IntObservable = _subject.AsObservable();
    }

    private int OnCallback(string Arr, int Len)
    {
        //do something
        var intValue = 0;
        _subject.OnNext(intValue);
        return intValue;
    }
    public IObservable<int> IntObservable { get; } 

}
```

I made `OnCallback` non-static, which differs from your solution. It would still work if static, but the `Subject` would have to be static as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at this:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    Observable
        .FromEvent<AutoReadCallback, int>(a => (pd, l) =>
        {
            var r = pd.Length + l;
            a(r);
            return r;
        }, h => foo.AutoReadCallback += h, h => foo.AutoReadCallback -= h)
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

    foo.OnAutoReadCallback("Bar", 2);
}

public delegate int AutoReadCallback(string pData, int Len);

public class Foo
{
    public event AutoReadCallback AutoReadCallback;

    public int OnAutoReadCallback(string pData, int len)
    {
        var arc = this.AutoReadCallback;
        if (arc != null)
        {
            return arc(pData, len);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

It's weird that an event handler returns a value so this code has some redundant looking code.